# I am getting error in printing the response of this API using flask

Tags: json, api, flask, flask-restful

I am new to Flask. I am making this call to this particular api but I am getting error which i am not able to solve after much searching also..because everytime i solve it..it pops some new error. This api should return json data but i think something is wrong with my syntax. Can anyone help me with this.

```
from flask.json import jsonify
from flask.templating import render_template
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def get_data():
    url = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=girls"
    data = requests.get(url)
    return data.json()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True, port = 3000)
```

Comment: Hi! Could you show an error? Thx :)

Comment: Yes..TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mensioned in comments, the problem in that you are trying to give `list` as response object. Flask can't do it. So, you should try to use `json` module like this:

```py
urlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dumped_json = json.dumps(urlist)
```

Output:

```py
>>> type(json.dumps(dumped_json))
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more..where should i store data from reuests.get(url)